# Redshift View Column Reassignment

Tags: sql, view, amazon-redshift

I have an existing view with a column A that has values 'Y' or 'N'

I need to create another column B that is just the inverse of column A. So when A = 'Y'  B = 'N'

Seems really simple but I cannot think of a way to do this within a view. I am trying to find a way to do it with a case that just says If column A = 'Y' then column B = 'N' and the other way around but am having issues

Anyone know of a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  Assuming `A` only takes on `'Y'` and `'N'`:

```
create view invert_a as
    select (case when A = 'Y' then 'N' else 'Y' end) as B, . . .
    from t;
```